# java: log4j: problem with jar executable

Tags: java, log4j

My log4j is working fine when I run "java pakcage.Main" from command line, but when I run the same program using executable jar like "java -jar myjar.jar" I'm getting the following err:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly
```

`log4j.jar` and `log4j.properties` are threre in my manifest's `Class-Path`.

I'm sure it worked properly once, but after rebuild it is not working.

Comment: a properties file can't be in a classpath. A jar or directory can be, but not a properties file. The directory containing log4j.properties (or the jar containing it) should be in the classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only list jar files or directories as part of a classpath. Instead of specifying log4j.properties you should specify the directory that the properties file is in relative to the jar being executed.

Example:

If myjar.jar in the base directory, log4j.jar in ./lib/ and log4j.properties in ./conf/

The Class-Path entry in myjar.jar as follows

Class-Path: lib/log4j.jar conf/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should also be able to simply include your log4j.xml (or log4j.properties) file inside of your custom Jar file. As long as it is in the root of your Jar file, the log4j framework will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

http://marc.info/?l=log4j-user&m=105168892203831&w=3